# Can not search in the database

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone help me?
I trying to create a very basic search function for my website, but i have an error, and i can not search from my database, the error like in the image that i attached with.[image]
It's ok when i enter the wrong name that is not exist on the database, but when i enter the name that is exist it will show the error like in the image, can anyone help me?
This is my php code:

```
<?php  
require_once("../../include/admin/ad_ovhead.php");
require_once("../../lib/connection.php"); 

$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", "", $searchq);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE firstname LIKE '%$searchq%' OR lastname LIKE '%$searchq%'";

    $query= mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Can not search");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
        $output= 'There are no search results!';
    }else{
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
            $firstname = $row['firstname'];
            $lastname = $row['lastname'];
            $id = $row['id'];

            $output .= '<div> '.$firstname.' '.$lastname.' </div>';
        }
    }

}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysqli_num_rows()` instead of `mysql_num_rows()`

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: it still doesn't work, and i don't know why,

Comment: What error do you get now?

Comment: still that error, it's ok when i search for the non.exist name, but when i search for the exist name, it's show the same error like before.

Comment: tks bro, i did fix that, i forgot to change  $row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) to mysqli, now it worrks